# Changing focus from Button in ListView row to list item

Tags: android, focus, android-listview, android-button

I have a `ListView` with list items that have a `Button` on them.  You can no longer select the list item, only the `Button` on the list item.  How do you change the focus back to the list item?

Comment: Have you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the `Button` in your list row layout add the attribute:

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Comment: Hi Slukian, thank you. I should still be able to click on the buttons right?

Comment: @user1164429  Yes. If you have elements like buttons , edittexts that take focus in the list row they will steal the focus from the list row.