# MvxListview binding button in item

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, mvvmcross, mvxlistview

i use a MvxListview and i need remove a item of this mvxlistview, each item of the mvxlistview contain 2 textview and one button, pressinf that button should remove the item, but didint work....i use a wrapper class but also dindt work any idea?

Comment: please post some code that you've already tried

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36360795/2754727