# MvxListVIew ItemLongClick binding with EditText in it

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin, mvvmcross

I want to have `EditText` within the `MvxListView` that has `ItemLongClick` binding working normally in it (using template). The development framework that I used is `MvvmCross` within Xamarin.Android (written in `C#`).

I have tried the normal approach, and the `EditText` seems taking all of the focusable within the `MvxListView` item. It means, the `ItemLongClick` only works within the `EditText` part of the item. It is important to know when I disable the focusable of `EditText` (`android:focusable="false"`), the `ItemLongClick` works within all part of the item (in sacrifice of `EditText` not working). The last thing that I have tried is set `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on my root element (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36336069/mvvmcross-mvxlistview-binding-multiple-clicks/36360795#36360795)) of my item layout and it acts the same as disabling the `EditText` focusable.

Below is the code I wrote.

**MvxListView in .axml**

```
...
<Mvx.MvxListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/table_shipment_item_layout"
    android:divider="#BCBCBC"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
    android:focusable="false"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource ScannedItems; ItemLongClick RemoveItemCommand;" />
...
```

**table_shipment_item_layout.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_clickable_item">
    ...
    <EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="16.0dp"
        android:text="5"
        android:padding="8.0dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#D3D3D3"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_textbox"
        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
        android:digits="0123456789."
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        local:MvxBind="Text Quantity;" />
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, I am using the `EditText`, so users are able to edit the quantity of every scanned item. Is there any workaround for this? I am also open to another method aside from `EditText` within `MvxListView` if there is any. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` is in your `Mvx.MvxListView` thats not working you need to add it to your root Layout of row row xml.

one more think you have declare  `android:focusable="false"` in `Mvx.MvxListView` thats is also not working you need to add in your child xml inner layouts like in your case `EditText` .

And as per experience  `EditText` in `ListView` not working properly .if you want to take input from each row separately.

You can take `TextView` in place of `EditText` and open and input `Dialog` with `EditText` and get your input value and set into your `TextView` and your DataList.

OR

you can create Custom `ListView` by using `ScrollView` and `Lienarelayout` and `EditText` ,in this way do not need to open and input `Dialog`.

Comment: Yes, I have tried all of those `descendantFocusability` and none of those works. They are there because I have not removed it after trying many times. Is there any other method you could suggest to overcome this issue based on your experience?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Is there any link or tutorial for using input `Dialog` with `EditText`? By using `ScrollView`, will it still use `local:MvxItemTemplate` and `ItemsSource` binding? If so, should the item template also stealing focusable of the parent?

Comment: you need to create one dialog while click on EditText . please follow this link for Dialog http://techblogon.com/alert-dialog-with-edittext-in-android-example-with-source-code/